# Extjs4 changing each bar color in bar chart

Tags: extjs4

I have a bar chart and i want each bar to render in different color. So i tried using thems,
sample code is:

```
             Ext.define('Ext.chart.theme.FancyTheme',{
extend : 'Ext.chart.theme.Base',

constructor : function(config){
    this.callParent([Ext.apply({
        colors : ['#9CC5C9','#D5544F','#D5544F','#5288DB']
    },config)])
}
});
```

and my chart code is:

```
        var tc = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart',{
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 500,
        height: 300,
        animate : true,
        insetPadding : 20,
        theme: 'FancyTheme',
```

But all the bar colors are changing to same color i.e, to '#9cc5c9' in above example.
But i want bars to render in differnt colors as mentioned in theme. One more thing i dont want to use render function to render coloirs.

So wat is the soln to get different colors. Can anyone help me out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but using a renderer is the correct solution. The `colors` property is used for successive series in a chart, such as multiple areas in the same plot space.

I don't understand why you don't want to use a renderer, but here's all you would need to do:

```
renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
    var colors = ['#9CC5C9','#D5544F','#D5544F','#5288DB'];

    return Ext.apply(attr, {
        fill: colors[index % colors.length]
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks.. and 1 more doubt is there any thing i can do in theme or any config option to change each bar colors?? if thr it ll be more helpful than this renderer function. Anyway thanks for ur response. It helped me.

Comment: This worked for me, even if I don't understand what "index" is. I have a 3 stacked values, and I expected index to be 0, 1 or 2. Instead it is very high value such 19325, 25031.. and so.. but using module operator works. Ext-magic

Answer (score 1):

You can also extend `Ext.chart.series.Bar`. For example:

```
Ext.define('Ext.chart.series.MyBar', {
    extend: 'Ext.chart.series.Bar',
    //type: 'mybar',
    alias: 'series.mybar',

    getPaths: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        var items = this.items, 
            i, iLen = items.length,
            colors = this.colorArrayStyle,
            colorsLength = colors && colors.length || 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < iLen; ++i) {
            items[i].attr.fill = colors[i % colorsLength];
        }
    }
});
```

Then in series you should use `mybar` instead of `bar`.

Comment: You don't need to. This is taken from theme as you wanted.